# the behavior about num.partitions in properties file

Tags: apache-kafka

I found the value of num.partitions is partition number on whole kafka cluster when auto topic was created.

I started 2 broker on my machine, brokerA and brokerB with its own server.properties (both num.partitons = 2), then I start a producer to write a message to kafka. I found each broker create 1 partition.

The problem is, when brokers in cluster each has its own different num.partitions, the logic of how many partitions of one topic will be obscure. For example, brokerA num.partiton=2, brokerB num.partitions=1. When a topic was auto created, how many partitions this topic will have?

I have tested this case but I can not find logical rules out. The behavior seems random, sometimes auto topic with 1 partition, sometimes 2.

Comment: You should try using configuration management tools to ensure the property files don't diverge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the design, the producer will choose a least-loaded broker to fetch topic metadata. For any non-existing topics, the chosen broker creates them with their own specified `num.partitions` if `auto.create.topics.enable` is true. By the least-loaded broker, it means the node with the fewest outstanding requests. In your test env, it might be brokerA sometimes but brokerB the other times. That's why you observe randomness.